# How to set sampling rate for digital pin input?

Tags: adc, digital-in

I have an ADC that have sampling rate up to 40 MSPS, but i use 8 MHz clock so it will be 8 MSPS. The board used is arduino nano. The problem is i have to sampling it just 2 MHz (because the capacity of array variable in arduino Nano, which is around 10.000 elements in array variable). I know that using direct port reading will increase the speed of the digital read, but how can i set the direct port reading to just read every 0.5 us? Micros function cannot do the job of course

Thank you

Comment: On what board...?

Comment: @Majenko edited, Arduino Nano

Comment: You don't *set* the sampling rate for a digital pin. You sample it in software by readinging the appropiate PORT*X* register (C,D,..). 500 nanoseconds is pretty on the edge. Only reading the PORT will cost you 125ns (and that's NOT doing any SPI logic -- if you bitbang SPI then this will be ONE BIT!) (https://github.com/NicksonYap/digitalWriteFast/blob/master/NOTES/NOTES.md)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt how can i set it in the software? AFAIK, using timer wont work because there is no timer with resolution 500ns

Comment: You can sample a digital port at 2 MHz, or even as fast as `F_CPU/3`, while storing the data in an array, but: 1. This needs assembly programming and, 2. It is very likely **not** what you want to achieve.

Comment: Of course, sampling too quickly will not allow the internal capacitor to stabilize at the input voltage.  I agree with @MaximilianGerhardt that 500 ms is a reasonable speed, determined by delay().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

1. A timer
2. A board that is capable of running fast enough to do what you want.

The Nano fits the first criteria, but not the second.

At 16MHz you get a clock period of 63ns.  That means you get a mere 8 clock ticks (actually gives you 504ns) per interruption from the timer. That's *at most* 8 assembly instructions that can be executed within that time.

Since an interrupt service routine's preamble is longer than 7 instructions you can see there would be a slight problem there.  No time for actually reading a digital IO port - and if you are using a serial protocol to communicate with your ADC you can multiply the reading time by the double the number of bits you need to read. That's a *long* time compared to 500ns.

So no. Think again. Use a more suitable board. Maybe an ARM based board (like the Teensy 3.x) would be a better fit.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: this is an attempt to answer the question as asked. This
answer is unlikely to be of any use to the original poster, who
presumably asked the wrong question. I am writing this only as a way to
explore the limits on how fast a modest AVR can sample a port. For an
answer that genuinely attempts to address the OP’s problem, see
Majenko’s answer.

I read the question as follows: can we sample a digital port at
2 MHz on an Arduino Nano clocked at 8 MHz? Can we do so while
storing the values in a RAM-based buffer?

The answer is yes, but it is non trivial, and it requires some assembly.
To see the problem, let’s start by trying to do it in C++:

```c++
uint8_t buffer[1024];

void fill_buffer()
{
    cli();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; i++)
        buffer[i] = PINB;
    sei();
}
```

Note that the loop runs with interrupts disabled, otherwise the timer
interrupt would wreak havoc with the loop timing. This is translated by
gcc into an assembly equivalent to this:

```
    cli
    ldi  r30, lo8(buffer)      ; load the buffer address into pointer Z
    ldi  r31, hi8(buffer)      ; ditto
0:  in   r24, 0x03             ; read the port
    st   Z+,  r24              ; store into buffer, increment the pointer
    ldi  r24, hi8(buffer+1024) ; save (buffer+1024)>>8 in r24
    cpi  r30, lo8(buffer+1024) ; compare the pointer with buffer+1024
    cpc  r31, r24              ; ditto
    brne 0b                    ; loop back
    sei
    ret
```

The loop takes 8 cycles per iteration. With an 8 MHz clock, that
would be one reading per microsecond. Too slow by a factor two.

One could save one cycle by using a different register for the port data
and for the end-of-loop condition, and by moving the third `ldi` out of
the loop. Another cycle could be saved by testing only the high byte of
the Z pointer, but that would require aligning the buffer to
256 byte boundaries. With those two optimizations, we still need
6 CPU cycles per iteration, i.e. 0.75 µs at 8 MHz.

In order to make this faster, the only solution is to unroll the loop.
This can be done in assembly by using the `.rept` (meaning “repeat”)
directive:

```c++
void fill_buffer()
{
    cli();
    asm volatile(
        ".rept %[count]\n"  // repeat (count) times:
        "in r0, %[pin]\n"   //   read the port input register
        "st Z+, r0\n"       //   store in RAM
        "nop\n"             //   1 cycle delay
        ".endr"
        ::      "z" (buffer),
        [count] "i" (sizeof buffer),
        [pin]   "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PINB))
        : "r0"
    );
    sei();
}
```

This takes 4 cycles, or 0.5 µs per iteration. Note that a
delay cycle had to be introduced, otherwise the sampling would be too
fast : 3 cycles, or 0.375 µs, per iteration.

This is not the fastest one can get. It is possible to take one sample
per CPU cycle with something like this:

```
    in r0, 0x03
    in r1, 0x03
    in r2, 0x03
    ...
```

However this technique is limited to burst readings of at most
32 samples.